# Bootstrap 3 removes padding/margin when I break under 767px width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When you look at that pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/eNpBdb

where I use bootstrap 3 css cdn attached.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <ul style="background:orange;" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a title="" href="http://test.com/en/deu/disclaimer/imprint.html" target="_self">disclaimer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a title="" href="http://test.com/en/deu/disclaimer/imprint.html#!/content=privacy" target="_self">Datenschutz</a>
        </li>
        <li><a title="" href="http://test.com/en/deu/disclaimer/site-map.html" target="_self">Sitemap</a>
        </li>
        <li><a title="" href="http://test.com/en/deu/disclaimer/contact.html" target="_self">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I resize my browser window to under 767px in width, why does the left margin/padding/space of the disclaimer hyperlink and all other 3 hyperlinks disappear?

Who removes that space? I need them as it looks very bad on small devices.

Answer (score 1):

The `row` class has

```
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px
```

The child column items have their own padding them.
This is meant to line up with the 
`container` that has

```
margin-left: 15px;
marign-right: 15px;
```

Solution: Remove the `row` class, or use the `column-xs-12` class for your child element.

Comment: Yep. Don't use rows without child columns.

Comment: @isherwood Where is that written? Any source please?

Comment: It's not written anywhere. It's inferred by reading the Bootstrap docs and understanding what SarahBourt wrote above. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

The classes you are using "container", "row", "nav", "navbar-nav" are all classes within bootstrap, because bootstrap is built to be responsive after browser resizing it will attempt to make it easier for smaller devices(phones, tablets, etc) to use this can be overcome by adding a custom css file under the bootstrap include and setting certain properties to !important.